# How to center jqPagination widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a pagination plugin called [jqPagination](http://beneverard.github.com/jqPagination/). The thing is that I want to center it in a parent container, but the widget uses "float:left" in the css which makes this hard.

If I remove the float:left, the widget somewhat breaks and since it doesn't use an explicit width, the old "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" trick doesn't work :(

How can I center this widget in a parent container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.clearfix` class ([clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)) to the jqPagination container and style

```
display: inline-block;
float: none;
```

After that wrap jqPagination container with another div and set `text-align: center;` for it.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, will accept as soon as I can :)

Comment: No problems. Btw I suggest you to read more about `clearfix`, extremely useful tool in some `float` cases.

Answer (score -1):

Your question lacks research and information.  I'd suggest adding too it.

Try:

```
margin-left: 50%;
```